# Packeteer Alternative

Tags: networking, monitoring, open-source, compression, traffic-shaping

I have been tasked with starting to monitor and restrict our companies internet access.  We have considered a Squid Proxy server but have decided we need something more robust then that. We would like many of the features commonly available on Packeteer products such as shaping, a web based GUI, and compression but truthfully we simple can't afford there often outrageous pricing. We have reviewed Cisco's option as well but it is equally cost restrictive.  Does anyone have any suggestions for a cheaper manufacture or provider of this type of equipment? We would be looking at filtering a pipe between 25-40MB (Tiered T3).

Comment: Womble why did you edit my post?  It certainly didn't originally say "decided we need something more expensive than that".  The original text used was "more robust than that" if you have something to say please post a comment.

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic per the FAQ.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend MasterShaper http://www.mastershaper.org/index.php/Main_Page . It has shaping, a web interface, is open source and has other features. It doesn't have compression.

In my former company (Internet Service Provider with a large base of users), we replaced a Packeteer PacketShaper with MasterShaper server and it works fine with traffic around 100 Mbps and thousand of connections at the same time. It's not the same as a hardware solution but maybe will fulfill your requirements.

Comment: May be good, but last news update is December 2007.

Answer (score 2):

Using PF on OpenBSD with a Sangoma's DS3 card might fill the bill for you.

www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/queueing.html

www.sangoma.com/products_and_solutions/hardware/

Comment: whoops! Perhaps not the Sangoma DS3, but rather the lmc DS3 card. More info at http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=lmc&arch=i386&sektion=4

Answer (score 1):

You might look at [Cymphonix](http://www.cymphonix.com/UserFiles/File/2470a_Brochure_v3_2[1].pdf) - we've got one on trial from a local reseller, and I haven't been able to dig into the thing yet, but it's doing enough shaping on our (admittedly MUCH smaller network) to fit our needs so far.

Answer (score 1):

Not tried this lot... but they're Yorkshire lads by the look of things, so they get my vote - look to have a credible product too:
[DBAM](http://www.dbamsystems.com/products/article/0/218)